# Using AJAX with forms created by a PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I run this all I get is the vars for the first form in the loop. I assume my problem is the forms are in an array and I have no idea how to get the distinct variables out of that array. I am a newbie. $id is always the same but the $law_id is always unique. I appreciate any help. This is for a game I am making that runs fine when I just post to another page but I would really like to keep it one page that just refreshes an output div. I have a couple loops in the code but I am sure if I get this one I can manage the rest.

This is my php loop that creates the forms:

```
    if ($num_rows > 0){
    while($data = mysql_fetch_object($ballots)){
    $law_id = $data->id;
    $question = $data->question;
    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM initiative_records WHERE initiative_id = '". $law_id ."' AND player_id = '". $id ."'";
    $new_ballots2 = mysql_query($query3,$link) or die("Unable to select: ".mysql_error());
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($new_ballots2);
        if ($num_rows == "0"){$x++;
        ?>
            <form name="initiative_create" class="form_inline">
            <input name="pid" type="hidden" value= "<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <input name="gid" type="hidden" value= "<?php echo $law_id; ?>">
            <input type="button" id="button" value="<?php echo $question; ?>" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost1("initiative_info.php")'>
            </form><br />
            <?php
        }
    }
```

my ajax script:

```
function xmlhttpPost1(strURL) {
var xmlHttpReq = false;
var self = this;
// Mozilla/Safari
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
// IE
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
        updatepage1(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
    }
}
self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring1());
}
function getquerystring1() {
    var form     = document.forms['initiative_create'];
var gid = form.gid.value;
var id = form.pid.value;
qstr = 'pid=' + escape(id) + '&' + 'gid=' + escape(gid);  // NOTE: no '?' before querystring
return qstr;
}
function updatepage1(str){
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
}
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? I find it difficult to understand what your problem is.

Comment: the html output gives me the looped forms but when I click on any of the forms I get the output for just the first form. That said I can dynamically make the post request ie initiative_info.php?gid="<?php echo $law_id; ?>"&pid="<?php echo $law_id; ?>" in the loop. Is there a simple ajax way to send just that without looking for the inputs?

Comment: So when you press the button you want to send the results of all of the forms in the page to the server?

Comment: no. just $gid and $pid of that form. What I am getting in the loop is a list of initiatives that the user then clicks to get more info on that particular initiative. So I need only the users id ($pid) and the initiatives id ($gid) sent to initiative_info.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign a unique name to each form and pass it to your function. Example:

```
<form name="initiative_create<?php echo $x; ?>">
...
<input type="button" id="button" value="<?php echo $question; ?>"
 onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost1("initiative_info.php", <?php echo $x; ?>)'>
```

And your functions would be

```
function xmlhttpPost1(strURL, name_index) {
...
self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring1(name_index));

function getquerystring1(name_index) {
...
var form     = document.forms['initiative_create' + name_index];
```

If I understood correctly and $x variable is a counter. If not, use $i or something.

I think you understand what and why I suggest to change.

Comment: $x is a counter for something else... I will try using $i. Thanks.

Comment: YES!!! Two days of headaches solved. Thank you very much! (I sell novelty toasters for a living... this is just something to keep the brain elastic.)

Comment: @JesusToasters You are welcome. Actually, it does not matter what counter you use, $x still should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with this line of code:

```
var form = document.forms['initiative_create'];
```

Since you're creating multiple forms with the same name only one of the will work.

I'd really recommend using a library like jQuery to make these kind of tasks easier for yourself. A similar script like above can be written in 4 lines of code:

```
$('form[name=initiative_create]').submit(function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#result').load('initiative_info.php', $(this).serialize());
});
```

Comment: I spent a day trying to use that library and couldn't get it to work. My java skills are lacking. PHP skills a little better but this is just a hobby I am picking up... one day I might try to get a library working. Even with a library I would have to make form name dynamically in a php loop to get it to work, right?

Comment: @JesusToasters You wouldn't have to give the form a unique name, since the selector `form[name=initiative_create]` retrieves all forms with the name 'initiative_create'. Including jQuery isn't difficult just add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` to your `head` before any other script tags.

Comment: @JesusToasters Also the language is called JavaScript not Java. JavaScript is to Java as car is to carpet.

Comment: I finally added the library and got it to work. Thank you for nudging me towards it.